# Немного о литературном плагиате

Tags: литература

Сейчас любят много говорить о защите авторских прав и т.д. А как быть с теми писателями, которые уже умерли и не могут защитить свои авторские права?
Я сейчас говорю о двух произведениях, которые смело можно назвать плагиатом: "Буратино" А. Толстого и "Волшебник Изумрудного города" Волкова. Первое - переделка "Пиноккио" К. Коллоди, второе - "Волшебника страны Оз" Л.Ф. Баума. И, если первое все-таки качественно переделано, то второе практически осталось без изменений за исключением некоторых имен и мелочей.
Вот и мне стало интересно: на каком основании тот же "Волшебник Изумрудного города" принято считать сказкой Волкова?

Answer (score 6):

Плагиат - это присвоение себе чужого интеллектуального труда. Если на этот труд дана ссылка и осуществлена значительная переработка сюжета как в обоих этих случаях, то это не плагиат, а произведение по мотивам. При любом раскладе, на уровне фабул количество различных вариантов сюжетов меньше полусотни (остальное - раскрытия и компиляции этих фабул), так что на этом уровне доказать плагиат литературного произведения почти невозможно.

Comment: > При любом раскладе, на уровне фабул, количество различных вариантов сюжетов меньше полусотни (остальное - раскрытия и компиляции этих фабул)

Очень интересное утверждение. Доказательство его справедливости потребовало бы, наверное, разработки полноценной теории. Я полагаю, как раз из такой теории это утверждение и почерпнуто Вами.

Comment: @Noir, таких теорий по вычленению архитипических сюжетов довольно много. Количество этих сюжетов в разных теориях разное, мне попадалось от 4 до 36. На всякий случай цифру в ответе увеличил до полусотни, но больше этой цифры - вряд ли, так как даже в теории с 36 сюжетами были явные повторы сюжетных ходов, вроде *жертва-самопожертвование*.

Comment: Интересно было бы, конечно, ознакомиться с одной из таких теорий, — интересно, но полезно ли? «Красоту можно убить, рассуждая, как она устроена».

Comment: @Noir, вот неплохая статья на эту тему. http://maxim-akimov.livejournal.com/268560.html

Comment: Спасибо, @Марк Из.

Comment: Не думаю, что "Волшебника Изумрудного города" можно назвать просто "вариантом сюжета". Изменено, насколько я помню, только имя главной героини с Дороти на Элли. И все. Разве нельзя это считать плагиатом?  
Сейчас есть понятие фэнфикшна, думаю, скорее, это оно. Только при написании такового ссылка на первоисточник обязательна, а в случае изменений авторской задумки обязательна пометка AU -  alternate universe, либо OOS - оut of сharacter.